# useCommonProps not working with next-i18next

Tags: typescript, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

I'm working on a project with next.js. When using `common-props` with `next-i18next` the defined props are missing from `pageProps` and from `useCommonProps()`.

### To Reproduce

I using `common-props` to get page specific data in layout components, in this case in the `<Navbar />`. I have a `common-props.config.js` file where I define the props:

```js
// common-props.config.js:

module.exports = () => ({
  ...,
  '/example/path/to/a/page': [
    { key: 'navbarStyle', data: () => 'dark' },
  ],
  ...,
});
```

And then I getting these props in the `<Navbar />` component. (`<Navbar />` component is rendered inside the `<Layout />` component):

```js
// src/components/nav/Navbar.tsx:

...
import useCommonProps from 'next-common-props/useCommonProps';
...

export default function Navbar() {
  ...

  const { common: { navbarStyle } } = useCommonProps();

  ...
}
```

In this case the `navbarStyle` value should be `'dark'` but instead now it's `undefined`. This is worked fine until I added `next-i18next` to the project. I noticed if I remove the `appWithTranslation` function from `src/pages/_app.tsx` it's working again. It's also missing from `pageProps`.

```js
// src/pages/_app.tsx:

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  ...

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default appWithTranslation(App);
```

### Expected behavior

I want to use `common-props` together with `next-i18next`. I assume that `appWithTranslation` function override some `pageProps` and that's why they are missing.

### Your Environment

- *runtime version*: `next: v13.1.5`, `node: v16.20.2`, `Brave browser: Version 1.59.117 Chromium: 118.0.5993.70 (Official Build)  (64-bit)`
- *i18next version*: `v23.5.1`
- *next-i18next version*: `v14.0.3`
- *react-i18next version*: `v13.2.2`
- *os*: `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`